# How to make one to many relations for rest api call in yii2

Tags: rest, yii, yii2

I have creating rest api call.

I have two table 
1. person - foreign key is id
2. contact - foreign key is personId

I have creating model for this one is

```
class  Group extends ActiveRecord
    {
        public function relations()
        {
            return array(
                'user'=>array(self::HAS_ONE,'User','id'),
                'contact'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Contact','personId')
            );
        }
    }
```

Controller is

```
public function actionView(){
        $group=Group::find();
        return $group;
}
```

Is this enough?. It is not working for me. How to make one to many relations in yii

Comment: your code is Yii 1.0 and your question title is Yii 2.0 so which Yii are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveModel::find()` returns an `ActiveQuery` instance, it doesn't run the query. 
You either use [`Group::findOne(primaryKey)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne()-detail) or [`Group::findAll(condition)`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll()-detail) or do [`return $group->one();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#one()-detail) or [`return $group->all();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#all()-detail)

As for the relations (in your model):

```
 public function getUser() 
 {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id', 'user']);
 }

 public function getContact()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Contact::className(), ['personId', 'user']);
 }
```

You call the with `$group->user` and `$group->contact`. Make sure not to use the function directly, it also returns an `ActiveQuery` instance, which is not your actual object.

Comment: So why did you create a Group ActiveRecord then? If it is using another table, override the `tableName()` function to return it.

Comment: You just added it in your own question... The Group class that extends ActiveRecord is a model.

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting your point. you have define some code for relations. Where i have to place the code and how can i call?